# How to copy files from colab or cloud storage to google drive?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I read some code on this problem, but i cannot make sense of the code. Could anybody help explaining the code to me?

```
# mount your drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!gsutil -q -m cp -r gs://my-bucket-name drive /content/drive/My\ Drive/
```

I want to transfer files from colab or google cloud storage to gdrive. What 'drive /content/drive/My\ Drive/' stands for in the code? how should I parse this piece of code. If it works for directory, how should I modify this piece of code to make it work for a single file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gsutil cp -r` does a recursive copy from one or more source files/dirs to some destination directory. E.g. to copy one or more directories into another directory, you'd do:

```
gsutil cp -r src_folder1/ src_folder2/ dst_folder/
```

So, let's explain what all is happening in your example above:

- You first mount the contents of your Google Drive, using some file system adapter magic under the hood via `drive.mount()`, under the local directory at `/content/drive`.
- You then run a `gsutil` command. `gsutil` sees the argument "drive" as another source file (or directory) that it should copy to the directory "/content/drive/My Drive/".  If the file/dir "drive" doesn't exist, gsutil skips it and complains that it didn't exist (but gsutil will still copy the other source arguments to the destination, due to the `-m` flag which causes it to continue (where possible) upon encountering a problem).

So, if you wanted to copy an object named "my-object-name" from your bucket to the root of your Google Drive, the command would look something like this:

```
!gsutil -q -m cp gs://my-bucket-name/my-object-name /content/drive/My\ Drive/
```

or, to copy the object and name it something different:

```
!gsutil -q -m cp gs://my-bucket-name/my-object-name /content/drive/My\ Drive/some-new-name
```

To read more about `gsutil`, its top-level flags, and its `cp` command, check out the web docs:

- [Gsutil Top-Level Command-Line Options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions)
- [Gsutil cp - Copy files and objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation!

Answer (score 7):

```
!cp "colab-path" -r "drive-path"
```

Comment: why -r ? I tried without -r and it works fine

Comment: Recursive copy for directory instead of single file.